# Arrow keys producing characters in gdb

Tags: terminal, gdb, command-line-interface, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've been using gdb (in Ubuntu 18.04 for Windows subsystem for Linux if that makes any difference) recently and for some reason the arrow keys do not seem to work. I get the characters left = 'K', right = 'M', up = 'H' and down = 'P'. Arrow keys seem to work normally in bash or zsh. I have tried different TERM modes (ansi, xterm, linux and my normal xterm-256color) but they do not seem to have any effect on the behavior. I can cycle through the command history in gdb with ctrl+p/n so that is working (and enabling the command history is the only thing I do in my ~/.gdbinit). What do I need to do to get the arrow keys working in gdb?

Comment: Do you have a ~/.inputrc file that sets some variables?

Comment: The only line I have in ~/.inputrc is "set revert-all-at-newline on" which prevents modifying history on the command line.